# Add pre-calculated confidence interval to seaborn tsplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Is it possible to add pre-calculated confidence intervals to a seaborn tsplot? For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(31),
                   'upper': np.random.rand(31)+1,
                   'lower': np.random.rand(31)-1,
                   'time': range(31)
                  })
df['subject'] = 0
sns.tsplot(data=df, value='value', time='time', unit='subject')

plt.show()
```

Is there a way to specify 'upper' and 'lower' for the confidence interval, using seaborn's built in CI plotters?

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to use `plt.fill_between`.